# Truffle TypeError: Member "error" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(library Assert)

Tags: solidity, truffle, ethereumjs, error, truffle-test

Trying to test my Solidity contract for errors using Truffle test.

TestSafeMath.sol

```
  function test_add_10_and_max_should_return_err() {
    uint256 max = 2**256 - 1;
    Assert.error(SafeMathExt.add(10, max), "Addition of 10 and max should return error?");
  }
```

Assert.sol

```
function error(uint16 errorCode, string message) constant returns (bool result) {
    result = (errorCode != 0);
    if (result)
        _report(result, message);
    else
        _report(result, _appendTagged(_tag(uint(errorCode), "Tested"), message));
}
```

Error Message:

```
TestSafeMathExt.sol:24:5: TypeError: Member "error" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(library Assert)
Assert.error(SafeMathExt.sub(0, 10), "Subscraction of 0 and 10 should return error?");
^----------^
```

Note: Other tests are working as expected

Comment: Side note: What's the point in returning something already known to you? (i.e. output `errorCode != 0`, when `errorCode` is the input).

Comment: Just to have a way for automated testing that the error actually occurs. At the same time I preferably would like to know the exact error that is thrown. I wanna make sure I am catching the overflow.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the error:

> TypeError: Member "error" not found or not visible after
> argument-dependent lookup in type(library Assert)

is saying that its looking through the Assert library and there's not a function named "equal" with a type signature matching what you're trying to pass.

In this case it looks like the `Assert.equal` function you're trying to use is expecting a uint16 and string to be passed to the function.  I'd suspect that `SafeMathExt.add(10, max)` in your example isn't returning uint16.